# Оформление Slick slider dots

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

Требуется поместить slick dots сверху (пробовал position, что приводит к перекрытию слайдера); 
и обязательно чтобы изображения у этих 3 точек были разными.

---

пробовал задать изображения через before, но ведь нужно для каждого элемента dots задавать отдельный класс, код будет раздуваться. Подскажите оптимальное решение

```css
.pager__item {
  padding: 0 12px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  &:before {
    display: block;
    content: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/outline-amenities-icon-set/64/Computer-128.png');
  }
 
}
```

[image: slider]

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/PKQWMJ?editors=1100

Comment: А если в шаблоне вывода слайдера поднять навигацию выше? Или нужно строго на css сделать?

Comment: в slick slider по умолчанию навигация внизу. А выше через css

Comment: Для слайдера slick есть в настройках параметр `appendDots`. Он определяет где навигация будет добавлена. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Создал контейнер сверху и прописал в js  appendDots:$('.dots-container'). Ничего не происходит

Comment: Просто нужно добавить немного css-магии :) https://jsfiddle.net/monobit/wb6zdm4r/

Comment: отлично, попробовал выводит undefined  https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/BdYQdB

Comment: Что мешает сделать 2 слайдера: слайдер со слайдами и слайдер-навигация и связать их свойством asNavFor? В навигационный слайдер положить картинки.

Comment: вполне согласен с решением 2 слайдера и asNavFor, ибо по другому нету смысла, before не гибкое решение если контент нужно будет добавлять в cms